# Как ограничить ширину canvas, fengyuanchen/cropper canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

У меня открывается фотография в модальном окне, она открывается как `canvas`. Проблема в том что Рамочка для вырезания может выходить за пределы фотографии, т.е. канвас по ширине больше с обеих сторон чем сама фотография. Возможно ли ограничить ширину canvas-а до ширины фотографии?

Comment: Возможно. Нужно динамически устанавливать `canvas` ширину и высоту. Для этого нужно определить длину и высоту фотографии

Comment: и как это сделать?)